# Java BufferedReader readLine method don't return nothing

Tags: java, console, java-io

I have a problem to resolve: http://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/problems/view/1117

With my code, when code reach the last line the method readLine don't return nothing. It waits i type other line of input.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

public class ValidacaoDeNota {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
      BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));

      String line = null;
      double num;

      Double ultimaNotaValida = null;

      while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
         num = Double.parseDouble(line);

         if (num < 0 || num > 10) {
            bw.write("nota invalida");
         } else if (ultimaNotaValida == null) {
            ultimaNotaValida = num;
         } else {
            bw.write("media = " + ((ultimaNotaValida+num) / 2) );
         }

         bw.write("\n");
      }

      bw.flush();
   }
}
```

Comment: Well it waits until it's got a line feed or knows that it's reached the end of the input, yes. That's what it's meant to do.

Comment: Your instructions says to read input from a file, why don't you use a FileInputStream instead? Using a FileInputStream it is easier to find out when there is end of input.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg Easier than readLine() returning null? Easier how exactly?

Comment: @EJP When reading from `System.in`, readLine() will not return null that easily but will instead wait for more input from the user.

Comment: @EJP Yes, I think it is easier to use FileInputStream than to produce a Ctrl-Z/Ctrl-D as input. But perhaps that's just me.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg The code required is almost exactly the same. What is different is what the user has to do.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enter Ctrl/d (Windows) or Ctrl/z (Unix, Linux etc) to produce an end of stream at the console. Then readLine() will return null and your loop will terminate.